# How would I make make my character counter work by not appearing inside an input box?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I'd like to know why whenever I switch the `<input>` tag to a `<p>` tag, my character counter doesn't appear at all.  I want the `Characters remaining:` part to not be inside an `<input>` tag.  I've tried a lot of ways to solve this but hit a wall, I just need another pair of eyes to see this.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?  JSFiddle provided for reference.

https://jsfiddle.net/2b38k9zt/

```js
var txtBoxRef = document.querySelector("#txtBox");
var counterRef = document.querySelector("#counterBox");
txtBoxRef.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
    var remLength = 0;
    remLength = 0 + parseInt(txtBoxRef.value.length);
    if(remLength < 0) {
        txtBoxRef.value = txtBoxRef.value.substring(0, 200);
        return false;
    } else if(remLength > 200) {
        counterRef.style.color = "red";
    }
    counterRef.value = "Characters remaining: " + remLength + "/200";
},true);
```

```html
<textarea style="width: 600px;" id="txtBox"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="counterBox"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your input to a p element and change this line

```
counterRef.value = "Characters remaining: " + remLength + "/200";
```

to

```
counterRef.innerHTML = "Characters remaining: " + remLength + "/200";
```

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

`input` tag has a `value` attribute, while for p tag `textContent` should be used:

```js
var txtBoxRef = document.querySelector("#txtBox");
var counterRef = document.querySelector("#counterBox");
var pRef = document.querySelector("#pBox");
txtBoxRef.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
    var remLength = 0;
    remLength = 0 + parseInt(txtBoxRef.value.length);
    if(remLength < 0) {
        txtBoxRef.value = txtBoxRef.value.substring(0, 200);
        return false;
    } else if(remLength > 200) {
        counterRef.style.color = "red";
    }
    pRef.textContent = "Characters remaining: " + remLength + "/200";
},true);
```

```html
<textarea style="width: 600px;" id="txtBox"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="counterBox"/>
<p id='pBox'></p>
```